# Substitute image with the default one if path not found

Tags: wpf

Image source for images are read from xml.  They are of the form pack://siteoforigin,,,image.jpg
If image isn't there then it's not displayed.  I'd like to show some default image instead, though.

Do I need create my converter where I would check that no such file exist and put the default one instead?  And then how would I check that.  I guess File.Exists("pack:....") will always be false.

Or there is an xaml way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`FallbackValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx), e.g.:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path, FallbackValue=PathToImageHere.png}"/>
```

Comment: Probably, why don't you just try it?